# Rounded corner using border radius for dynamically generated li

Tags: php, html, border, border-radius

I'm having trouble rounding just one corner of my ul list. The last one specifically. Right now, all the corners on the bottom are rounded. Here is my code php code:

```
 <div class="container">
  <?php
  $pagination = $products->pagination();?>
  <?php foreach($pagination->range(10)as $r): ?>
    <div class="paginator">
      <ul>
        <li><a<?php if($pagination->page() == $r) echo ' ' ?> href="<?php echo $pagination->pageURL($r) ?>"><?php echo $r ?></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <?php endforeach ?>
```

and my css:

```
.paginator a:active {
  background-color: #2A4143;
  color: #fff;
}

.paginator {
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;

}

.paginator ul {
  margin-right: -4px;
}
/*.paginator ul{*/
/*  width: 100%;*/
/*  margin-left: auto;*/
/*  margin-right: auto;*/
/*  !*position: absolute;*!*/
/*  !*bottom: 0;*!*/
/*  !*left:0;*!*/
/*  !*right:0;*!*/
/*}*/

.paginator ul li a {
  /*float: left;*/
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  border: 1px solid #2A4143;
  /*border-right-width: 0;*/
  margin-right:-1px;
  margin-bottom:-1px;
  display: inline;
  /*display: inline;*/
  /*display: block;*/
   /*max-height: 100px;*/
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.paginator li:last-child a {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

I saw a few solutions on Stack Overflow and elsewhere, but it doesn't really handle a dynamically generated list.

Answer (score 1):

figured it out.
I moved the class on top of the php.

```
 <div class="container">
      <?php
      $pagination = $products->pagination(); ?>
      <div class="paginator">
        <ul>
      <?php foreach ($pagination->range(10) as $r): ?>
            <li><a<?php if ($pagination->page() == $r) echo ' ' ?>
                href="<?php echo $pagination->pageURL($r) ?>"><?php echo $r ?></a></li>

      <?php endforeach ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and changed the CSS like so:

```
.paginator ul {
  margin-right: -4px;
  display: flex;
}
```